# Change Text and Image On Static Website Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a static website and its online now. I want to change only some text and image Dynamically, So that I dont have to change the code for change text or image. Please suggest me a simple way.

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a place where code is written for you. **Share the code** of your previous attempts so that we can **help** you further and not take over your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a static website, I think it is not possible unless you have set up some administrator stuff or you created that website using frameworks such as Wordpress or WIX.